# I have a ghost folder in my left bar in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, directory

I have a ghost folder in my left bar in nautilus which is called "Muziek" (Which is translated to "Music")

[image: Muziek = Music in english]

I want to remove it but I cant, because I can't even find it!

[image: Everything is unkown!]
(onbekend = unkown)

[image: No rights?!]
(This means there are no rights)

So, does anyone know how I can remove it from there?

The output of cat `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` is:

```
file:///home/xyz/Documenten
file:///home/xyz/Muziek
file:///home/xyz/Afbeeldingen
file:///home/xyz/Video's
file:///home/xyz/Downloads
```

The output of `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` is:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Bureaublad"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Sjablonen"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Openbaar"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documenten"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Afbeeldingen"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Video's"
```

(I already tried to comment out XDG_MUSIC_DIR but no change!)

Ubuntu version: 17.10 (64 bit)

I did NOTHING to get it there (and it has nothing to do with with my USB, BACKUP USB or Floppy!)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? please [edit] your question to include the output of terminal command `cat ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`

Comment: I have 17.10, too, and I also see a folder Music. But here it is just a plain empty folder - nothing particular. When I click on properties it says 'type: folder, contents: nothing' which is correct. I don't know what went wrong with your Dutch version.

Comment: @muclux yours is probably above the trashcan and mine is everything: unkown but my correct music folder (above the trashcan) says: type: folder (or type: map) and contents: nothing (or inhoud: niets)

Comment: Exactly as you said.   Could you look at `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking it and cosing  to remove it from the pinned list? :) otherwise check if the file mentioned by @muclux is involved :)

Comment: I see in your `user-dirs.dirs` that the music directory is not correctly defined. Did you try to complete it to `XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Muziek"` like the other entries?

Comment: @Videonauth Thank you for the editing. I tried to do it before but I was told that I had to edit at least 6 characters although I added 20 spaces for the formatting.

Comment: Yes can be a bit tricky, but if you have a look at the [edit history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/982746/revisions) you will see that there have been over 6 characters to change :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those Ghost folders happen when you change around the names of the different top entries by hand in terminal. Usually it is enough to right-click on the ghost entry and choose to remove it from the side bar.

[image]

But before that make sure the entries in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` match the actual folder names you are using right now and do a reboot. The actual folder names should how up on the top part in nautilus, then right-click the ghost entries and choose remove which will remove them from the view.

[image]